# Performing Calculation in Default MySQL Value

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to performing calculations based on value of some other column within same or different table using the Default Value property (that is, the `DEFAULT` clause on a column definition) of MySQL ?

We can set static default values to any column but can we perform calculations or query other tables' data ??

**EDIT**

Let's say a table with column for `marks` and other with `total_marks` and third column `percentage`. How to set default value of `percentage` to be calculated from the former two columns

Comment: Yes. If you provide some more information perhaps we can give you more ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The value for the DEFAULT clause must be a constant. (The one exception to this rule is the use of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value for a `TIMESTAMP` column.)

As an alternative, you can use a TRIGGER to set a value for a column when a row is inserted or updated.

For example, within a BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW trigger, you can perform calculations from values supplied for other columns and/or query data from other tables.

---

**EDIT**

For the example given in the EDIT of the question, an example starting point for a trigger definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_bi 
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.percentage = (100.0 * NEW.marks) / NULLIF(NEW.total_marks,0);
END
```

Comment: I had misunderstood the question.  Using a trigger is the right answer!  +1 for managing to work out what was being asked :)

Comment: i too believe triggers are the way to go but I wanted to know if Default value could handle it. I guess it can't.

Comment: I had trouble with running this until I understood a problem I was having with delimiters. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html, which says "if you use the mysql program to define a trigger that executes multiple statements, it is necessary to redefine the mysql statement delimiter so that you can use the ; statement delimiter within the trigger definition".

Answer (score 1):

The trigger solution is great, but I came here with a slightly different situation and that solution is not what I was looking for.

I am using the default value for the one and only time I add the new column to the table. In any other situation I will not be using that default value. So I don't want to have a trigger.

I think in this case, the only option is to default the value to 0 (or any particular value). Then update all these freshly inserted 0's with the value needed from the calculation.

Finally, update the default value of that new column to whatever is needed from now on.

Comment: I had the same situation. I think I'll put in a default that works for the highest percentage of rows and then run an `UPDATE` to fix the rest. I'm using Liquibase so I can put it into the same `changeSet` and the rollback just requires removing the column.