# Looking for MySQL Default yesterday date

Tags: mysql, sql, unix, terminal

I am using MySql via terminal. Below is the command I have used to create table but it is showing date in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (example: 2018-05-25 14:12:47)

```
create table test (foo int, ts timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

[image: Screenshot for the same]

But I want by default it take yesterday date every time I insert data in (YYYY-MM-DD) format.

Please help me to find the command.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: I believe this has already been answered on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163263/performing-calculation-in-default-mysql-value

Comment: No dear, I am looking for auto update of yesterday date only... there is no link with the post you have shared.

Comment: @AmitRai That link says clearly that you _can't_ do this in MySQL.  You will need to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official MySQL documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add, you can do like this:

If you want to store the "yesterday" on creation:

```
ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If you want to store the "yesterday" on every update:

```
ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

According to this answer [Select records from NOW() -1 Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544438/select-records-from-now-1-day):

> NOW() returns a DATETIME.
>
> And INTERVAL works as named, e.g. INTERVAL 1 DAY = 24 hours.
>
> So if your script is cron'd to run at 03:00, it will miss the first
>   three hours of records from the 'oldest' day.
>
> To get the whole day use CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY. This will get
>   back to the beginning of the previous day regardless of when the
>   script is run.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Expressions are not allow for such defaults.

Answer (score 0):

DEFAULT values in MySQL must be constants. They can't be functions or expressions (with the exception of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Source: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html](http://%20http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html)

In addition you can add a trigger to your table for your requirement

Simply Create a Table without constraint

```
create table test (foo int, ts timestamp );
```

Then add a trigger to this table

```
CREATE TRIGGER settime
BEFORE INSERT on test 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF new.`ts ` is null THEN
    SET new.`ts ` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY);
    END IF;
END;
```